# Conditional coloring of histogram graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, histogram, matlab-guide

I have a histogram that I want conditional coloring in it with this rule :

**Values that are upper than `50` have `red` bars and values lower than `50` have `blue` bars.**

Suppose that we have this input matrix:

```
X = [32 64 32 12 56 76 65 44 89 87 78 56 96 90 86 95 100 65];
```

I want default bins of MATLAB and applying this coloring on X-axes (bins). I'm using GUIDE to design my GUI and this histogram is an axes in my GUI.

[image]

This is our normal graph. Bars with upper values than 50 should be red and bars with lower values than 50 should be green (X-axes). Bars with upper values than 50 should be red and ?

Comment: Is `X` the histogram or the input on which the histogram will be computed?

Comment: X is data for input of histogram.

Comment: And the division based on 50 applies to the x axis (bins) or to the y axis (count)?

Comment: And how do you want histogram bins to be defined? That is, how many bins and at which position? Maybe edit your question to show your current histogram code

Comment: With default Matlab bins, a bin can include values both above and below 50 (for example, the bin may correspond to the intervalo 45-55). How do you deal with that?

Comment: I'm coloring only on X-axes. suppose that we have vertical line on 50. Bars on left hand side of it should be green and bars on right hand side of it should be red.

Comment: If all bars are greater than 50, so all of them must be red.

Comment: So you mean if the _center_ of the bar is above/below 50, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want (as per comments). The bar around 50 is split into the two colors. This is done by using a patch to change the color of part of that bar.

```
%// Data:
X = [32 64 32 12 56 76 65 44 89 87 78 56 96 90 86 95 100 65]; %// data values
D = 50; %// where to divide into two colors

%// Histogram plot:
[y n] = hist(X); %// y: values; n: bin centers
ind = n>50; %// bin centers: greater or smaller than D?
bar(n(ind), y(ind), 1, 'r'); %// for greater: use red
hold on %// keep graph, Or use hold(your_axis_handle, 'on')
bar(n(~ind), y(~ind), 1, 'b'); %// for smaller: use blue
[~, nd] = min(abs(n-D)); %// locate bar around D: it needs the two colors
patch([(n(nd-1)+n(nd))/2 D D (n(nd-1)+n(nd))/2], [0 0 y(nd) y(nd)], 'b');
%// take care of that bar with a suitable patch
```

[image]

Comment: What is your idea about a bar near 50? a part of this specific bar is upper than 50 and a part is lower than 50. How can I have different colors in that bar?

Comment: @user2991243 I'm considering the bar _center_ to determine color. That's what I understood from your comments. So if the center is greater than 50, I use red

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer. Can we have different coloring in this specific bar? Some part of this bar must be blue and other part(bigger part) must be red.

Comment: And can we remove spaces between bars?

Comment: @user2991243 What do you mean "some part"? Like, dividing the bar vertically? That's tricky. To remove spaces: add `1` as a third parameter to `bar`: `bar(n(~ind), y(~ind), 1, 'b');` etc

Comment: Yes. I think that's so tricky :-). Suppose that we have vertical line on 50. All element in right hand side of this line are red and others are green. Now we have a bar near 50 that some part of it is read and other part is green.

Comment: I think you need to draw the bars manually with `patch`. The bar around 50 will have to be drawn in two parts

Comment: Another problem. I use something like `bar(handles.axes2,n(ind), y(ind), 'r')` and `bar(handles.axes2,n(~ind), y(~ind), 'b');` because there are other elements in my GUI and I'm referring to a specific axes. I'm suing `hold on` between them as you mentioned. Now only I have blue bars (lower than 50). How can I solve this?

Comment: @user2991243 I solved it with just one `patch` for the bar around 50. As for `hold on`: replace it by `hold(handles.axes2,'on')`

Comment: @user2991243 Welcome :-) There was an error in the `patch` line; please see now

Comment: How can I connect this patch to `handles.axes2`? In your code it is referring to another axes in my window.

Comment: `patch` draws on the current axis. So use `axes(handles.axes2)` before `patch` to make your axis the current one

Answer (score 0):

First sort X:

```
X = [32 64 32 12 56 76 65 44 89 87 78 56 96 90 86 95 100 65]; 
sorted_X = sort(X)
```

sorted_X :

sorted_X =

Columns 1 through 14

```
12    32    32    44    56    56    64    65    65    76    78    86    87    89
```

Columns 15 through 18

```
90    95    96   100
```

Then split the data based on 50:

```
idx1 = find(sorted_X<=50,1,'last');
A = sorted_X(1:idx1);
B = sorted_X(idx1+1:end);
```

Display it as two different histograms.

```
hist(A);
hold on;
hist(B); 
h = findobj(gca,’Type’,’patch’);
display(h) 
set(h(1),’FaceColor’,’g’,’EdgeColor’,’k’);
set(h(2),’FaceColor’,’r’,’EdgeColor’,’k’);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where `gca` referring to? My axes in my GUI?

Answer (score 0):

```
X = [32 64 32 12 56 76 65 44 89 87 78 56 96 90 86 95 100 65];
```

then you create an histogram, but you are only going to use this to get the numbers of bins, the numbers of elements and positions:

```
[N,XX]=hist(X);
close all
```

and finally here is the code where you use the Number of elements (N) and the position (XX) of the previous hist and color them

```
figure;
hold on;
width=8;
for i=1:length(N)
    h = bar(XX(i), N(i),8);
    if  XX(i)>50
        col = 'r';
    else
        col = 'b';
    end
    set(h, 'FaceColor', col)
end
```

here you can consider using more than one if and then you can set multiple colors

cheers