# 3D histogram and conditional coloring

Tags: matlab, if-statement, histogram

I have a series of ordered points (X, Y, Z) and I want to plot a 3D histogram, any suggestions?

I'm trying to do it by this tutorial http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html , but points are random here and presented as a function. My example is easier, since i already know the points.

Furthermore, depending on the number value of Z coordinate, i'd like to colour it differently. E.g. Max value - green, min value - red. Similar as in this case [Conditional coloring of histogram graph in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219816/conditional-coloring-of-histogram-graph-in-matlab), only in 3D.

So, if I have a series of points:

```
X = [32 64 32 12 56 76 65]
Y = [160 80 70 48 90 80 70]
Z = [80 70 90 20 45 60 12]
```

Can you help me with the code for 3D histogram with conditional coloring?

So far the code looks like this:

```
X = [32 64 32 12 56 76 65];
Y= [160 80 70 48 90 80 70];
Z= [80 70 90 20 45 60 12];
A = full( sparse(X',Y',Z'));
figure; 
h = bar3(A); % get handle to graphics
for k=1:numel(h), 
    z=get(h(k),'ZData'); % old data - need for its NaN pattern
    nn = isnan(z); 
    nz = kron( A(:,k),ones(6,4) ); % map color to height 6 faces per data point 
    nz(nn) = NaN; % used saved NaN pattern for transparent faces 
    set(h(k),'CData', nz); % set the new colors
end
colorbar;
```

Now I just have to clear the lines and design the chart to make it look useful. But how would it be possible to make a bar3 without the entire mesh on 0 level?

Comment: Does this not cover your application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180890/3d-histogram-with-gnuplot-or-octave ? In particular this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24550095/1011724

Comment: Very close indeed @Dan , didn't find this before, thanks! The main issue I have is that here the points are given all in Z - in a row. I'd like to have X-Y point, with Z height. Which is what i find hard to implement here...

Comment: I think you could create the require `Z` form quite easily using `sparse` and `full`

Comment: So try use that code in the second link and create their `Z` like this: `Z = full(spares(X',Y',Z'))`, then you just need to work out how to clear the edge lines

Comment: @Dan Have any suggestions how to "clear" the chart? As it stands, matrices(?) are seen over the chart.

Comment: Add what? :) Go ahead...

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I added a way to "clear" the chart if by clear you mean get rid of the black edge lines and the blue base (i.e. all the zero height bars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180890/3d-histogram-with-gnuplot-or-octave/24550095#24550095), all you need to do is rearrange your data to match the `Z` format of that answer. After than you might need to remove edgelines and possibly clear the zero height bars.

```
% Step 1: rearrange your data
X = [32 64 32 12 56 76 65];
Y= [160 80 70 48 90 80 70];
Z= [80 70 90 20 45 60 12];
A = full( sparse(X',Y',Z'));

% Step 2: Use the code from the link to plot the 3D histogram
figure; 
h = bar3(A); % get handle to graphics

set(h,'edgecolor','none'); % Hopefully this will remove the lines (from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/281581)

for k=1:numel(h), 
    z=get(h(k),'ZData'); % old data - need for its NaN pattern
    nn = isnan(z); 
    nz = kron( A(:,k),ones(6,4) ); % map color to height 6 faces per data point 
    nz(nn) = NaN; % used saved NaN pattern for transparent faces 

    nz(nz==0) = NaN; % This bit makes all the zero height bars have no colour

    set(h(k),'CData', nz); % set the new colors. Note in later versions you can do h(k).CData = nz
end

colorbar;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dan . Sorry to bother you, but would you perhaps know why do i get such result as on this image [link](http://shrani.si/f/3t/QW/44alnEU2/napaka.png) I am referring to this numbers allover the chart

Comment: Weird, what version of MATLAB did you use? Was that just copying and pasting my code? Same inputs and everything?

Comment: Yes, i only added "axis equal" extra code. The version is R2001b 7.13.0.564 - i should probably get a newer version right

Comment: I mean what year? Is that R2011? without `axis equal` did it work?

Comment: On an older version I would say try some of the other answer's form that link, such as [Amro's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24567637/1011724). They are built for Octave and so I would think that they would also work on older versions of MATLAB. I have no idea what's happening on your image I'm afraid.

Comment: Dan. I have installed a 2014 version and it works perfectly! Thanks again, look great!